# OpenRasta URI Maps to Wrong Method and returns inconsistent http status codes

Tags: get, http-status-codes, openrasta

I'm using OpenRasta framework in a .net service and I have two methods as below in the handler

```
public OperationResult Get(int Number)
{
// Do some operation and get an entity
  return new OperationResult.OK(Single-MyResource);
}

public OperationResult GetQ()
{
// Do some operation and get an entity
  return new OperationResult.OK(List-Of-MyResource);
}
```

My configuration looks like below

```
ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<MyResource>()
          .AtUri("/MyResource/{Id}")
          .And.AtUri("/MyResource")
          .HandledBy<MyResourceHandler>()
          .AsJsonDataContract() 
          .And.AsXmlDataContract()


 ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<IList<MyResource>>()
         .AtUri("/MyResources") 
         .HandledBy<MyResourceHandler>()
         .AsJsonDataContract()
         .And.AsXmlDataContract();
```

HttpMethod: GET
AcceptHeader: "application/json"
URI: http://testDomain.com/MyResource/

The above request gives me the List of MyResource , same as what i get for the below Request

HttpMethod: GET
AcceptHeader: "application/json"
URI: http://testDomain.com/MyResources/

After changing Configuration to

```
ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<MyResource>()
          .AtUri("/MyResource/{Id}")
          .And.AtUri("/MyResource").Named("MyResource")
          .HandledBy<MyResourceHandler>()
          .AsJsonDataContract() 
          .And.AsXmlDataContract()
```

and making appropriate change in handler i.e

```
[HttpOperation(HttpMethod.GET, ForUriName = "MyResource")]
```

OpenRasta returns 415 http Status Code.

The above is not consistent again.

For my other Resource for similar configuration as above
OpenRasta throws 403 http Status Code

Answer (score 1):

The first case is correct. You share a handler between the two. As such, when the handler is looked at to select a method, there is one candidate with a parameter and one without. When you to to /MyResource, it finds the handler and find the method that has no parameter. This is expected behavior.

In your second configuration, there's something missing there. A 415 is when the request data is not understood by OR. As it's a GET, there should be no request media type to deal with. This one will require a debug log to check what is going on. Are you sure your request is not coming with some request data and a Content-Type?

Comment: Yes, My request is not passing any data and Content-Type.

Comment: Details of the Request while executing on Fiddler.                GET http://testDomain.com/RestLayer/MyResource                      Request Headers

User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: testDomain.com
Authorization: token abcabaabcacbacba
                                                                                   Status returned is 415

Answer (score 0):

The GET side of OpenRasta, I have got pretty well in my mind, It's the POST I still struggle with:

I've done really similar things to you for JSON only, but done it like this:

```
    ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<IList<MyResource>>()
                .AtUri("/myresource").And
                .AtUri("/myresource/{id}").HandledBy<ResourceHandler>().AsJsonDataContract();



    [HttpOperation(HttpMethod.GET)] 
    public IEnumerable<MyResource> Get(int id = 0)
    {
        if (id == 0)
            return Context.Set<MyResource>().ToList();
        else
            return GetMyResourceMethod(id).ToList();
    }

    private IQueryable<MyResource> GetMyResourceMethod(int id)
    {
        var myresource = from resource in Context.Set<MyResource>()
                      where resource.MyResourceId == id
                      select resource;
        return myresource;
    }
```

You can handle both with and without parameters with a default parameter in your Get method.  I think from your second configuration your missing the IList from your ResourceType because the non parametered option will return a list.  It is then impreitive to return a IEnumerable via the ToList() method.

This all assumes your using SQL-to-Linq in your 'List-Of-MyResource', but I can't see that part of your code and what it is doing.  If not just ignore the private function I've included and take your own approach.